# Create a collectionView from an existing tableView data source and controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

So i've been working on an **ePub** framework called `Readium` and they recently created an SDK for IOS.

The SDK is a full working project that allows a user to select an ePub from a `tableView` list and after selecting one gives you meta-data about that ePub after which you have to select the page list or spine items and after selecting one of the pages it finally goes to the ePub.

I want to streamline this process by opening with a list of ePubs in a `collectionView` and after selecting an ePub make it go straight to the first/cover page of that ePub.

What I want to know is if it is possible to use the `viewController` and *data sources* of the `tableView` to create a new `collectionView`? I have already adapted this project to allow Swipe Navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do it quite quickly.

1) You have to tell the controller that you want to adapt collection view, so you have two options in your `.h` file:

a) If you are currently inheriting from UITableView - **inherit your ViewController from UICollectionViewController**:

```
@interface YouViewControllerName : UICollectionViewController
```

b) If you **inherit from UIViewController**, just **set** your **controller** **conforming to CollectionView** delegate and dataSource methods like this

```
@interface YouViewControllerName : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource> { ... }
```

**2)** Then you need to **replace table view delegate and data source methods** **with collection view data source and delegate methods**, so you need to replace something like this:

Old:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ... }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { ... }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { ... }
```

New:

```
- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                           cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ... }

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section { ... }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView { ... }
```

So the **content** within your previous delegate/datasource methods **could remain same**, as the logic is not needed to change.

You may need to implement some more specific methods and to have some work with designing right item cell sizes etc., but is is natural as your layout is replaced by collection view.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I needed to create new classes for this but i'll try and do it this way and ill see how I go :)

Comment: Yeah, you can also create new classes, it can be actually the better way, if you have no experiences yet and then you would keep your original methods safe. :)

Comment: One more thing what if the data source and delegate is inherited from a `ContainerController` and the table utilises this, can I just add the `UICollectionViewDelegate' and 'UICollectionViewDataSource` to the existing container? To be more clear that section of the file currently looks like this:
`@interface ContainerController () <
 RDContainerDelegate,
 UITableViewDataSource,
 UITableViewDelegate,
 UIAlertViewDelegate`

Comment: Well you should mention that... This you may to set up differently. But the logic is the same. The Container controller should comform to collection view in the same manner.

Comment: What is `RDContainer`? If it is related to TableViewController, it can be problem. If not, go ahead.

Comment: So I dont need to recreate the interface? I can just adapt the existing one by adding: `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource`

Comment: Yes you have to adapt it, as in the step 1 I described in my answer.

Comment: `RDContainer` is an `NSObject` that contains the package details for the ePubs being viewed. From what I can see I dont think it interacts directly with any `viewController`

Comment: Fine, so you could adapt it without issues. I'm curious whether you achieve the goal.

Comment: Even without creating the separate classes for the `UICollectionView` just creating all the functions for the cells is quite tough. There a lot of other classes and functions within the `UITableView` that aren't in the `UICollectionView`. However I did manage to create a `UICollectionView` with cells. Now I just need to figure out how the data for **ePubs** is collected and stored in the other classes. Im still trying to decipher how to get the first page on the front of the cell and have a Label with text on top of that. @pedrouan thanks for the head start I owe you a coffee

Comment: Cool, I am glad you managed. If you'd need, place a question and notify me by any comment, anytime. Thanks for the coffee, voting/acceptation could be enough ;)

Comment: Hahah when I get it right successfully i'll accept the answer. So far so good though, just gotta understand `UICollectionView` a bit better. I did upvote the answer

Comment: I've accepted @pedrouan's answer because in terms of getting a basic `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell` for this particular project and framework, this answer is ideal to get something done quickly. Technically new classes should be built for the **collection view**